# MongoDB Kafka Source Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the MongoDB Source connector -

I have created the DB with name `testDB` & a collection named `init`

Following is the connector config -

```
{
    "name": "mongo-source-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo:27017",
        "database": "testDB",
        "collection": "init"
    }
}
```

I have tried using multiple different properties which are mentioned in MongoDB connector doc but always got some error.

Following is the error -

```
2023-07-05 18:43:27 [2023-07-05 13:13:27,026] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unexpected error: null
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.StartedMongoSourceTask.getNextBatch(StartedMongoSourceTask.java:597)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.StartedMongoSourceTask.pollInternal(StartedMongoSourceTask.java:211)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.StartedMongoSourceTask.poll(StartedMongoSourceTask.java:188)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask.poll(MongoSourceTask.java:173)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.poll(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:462)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:351)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:75)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-07-05 18:43:27 at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.StartedMongoSourceTask.getNextBatch(StartedMongoSourceTask.java:579)
2023-07-05 18:43:27 ... 14 more
```

Following is the version details -
`confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`: `latest`

`confluentinc/cp-kafka`: `latest`

`confluentinc/cp-schema-registry`: `latest`

`confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect`:`latest`

`mongo`: `latest`

Plugin:

`mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb`: `1.10.1`

Just a note that the sink connector works fine